# Where to put singleton using getX?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I need to create a firebase singleton over through the whole application. so i create firebase singleton inside the main. Is this a right way? where should i close this singleton?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Get.put<FirebaseAuth>(FirebaseAuth.instance, permanent: true);
  Get.put<FirebaseFirestore>(FirebaseFirestore.instance, permanent: true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Try using it this way. https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example

Answer (score 1):

I have used firebase for my notifications and I created the configuration in a class with getx and in the main I only use the put

my main is as follows

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Get.put(PushNotificationController());
  runApp(...)
}
```